# What's the right way for me to ask for help crafting a great answer to a question I already know how to answer?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

In [Why does check.torproject.org sometimes tell me I'm not using Tor, when I am?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/190/why-does-check-torproject-org-sometimes-tell-me-im-not-using-tor-when-i-am) I've tried to raise an important and somewhat common question, where nobody in the Tor community has written down any good clear comprehensive answers yet. But, as the local area expert here, I already know the answer in the general sense -- I just want help from everybody to write it in a clear way.

I guess the first question is, am I on-topic by asking such a question with that motivation?

And second, what's the best way for me to guide answers? Should I include only the question in the question, and use the comments section to suggest components that the answer should be sure to hit? Or is the way I did it an accepted way? Or what?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Its really awesome when users share the knowledge that they already have in Q&A form. Stack Exchange [encourages self-answered questions.](https://tor.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) I am not going to repeat whats mentioned in the FAQ and blog here, but in short, any such questions written in good faith, describing real issues that users' face, are welcome.

You are entirely free to write answers to them as well. In fact, you can even write multiple answers to your own questions too (not recommended, but you can). If you would like to write a partial answer and let the community improve on that one answer, you could create a community wiki post by clicking on the checkbox on the bottom right corner of the answer interface. This allows any user to edit and add/remove content to the post.

Other than that, you could just let answers come as they may, and then maybe improve them where you see fit.

My recommended approach would be to wait for 1-2 days, and then submitting a CW answer (if you believe you cannot answer the question fully) or a normal answer (if you believe you can do justice to the question).

As far as guiding answers is concerned, putting in information into the question is good, however it should still be in the form of a question. You will see this in some of the [changes that I made](https://tor.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/124) to your question. Any more information should be either edited into answers, requested or pointed out to other users using comments once they answer. Basically, your questions should just be a question.

My reasoning for this approach is that, the question is intended to be from the point of view of a Tor user (as you mention), who may not be aware of how Tor works. So, the post should be phrased from their point of view, and not yours. If a user were to see the question, then its likely they would stop reading once they stopped comprehending the question content. Also, since they could not understand the question itself, they would be much less likely to stay and read long canonical answers. Therefore, your question would not actually help the target audience for whom it is intended. So, questions should contain only questions within them, and any guidance for answers should be given through comments or by direct edits, if you would not like to answer yourself.

Hope this clears things!

Answer (score 0):

I like the way you phrased the question with potential good answers included.

It's not against the rules to answer your own question, especially since you may be the one who best knows the answer anyway. I would think leave it unanswered for maybe  2 weeks before doing so and hopefully it will happen organically.

Comment: It is encouraged to answer your own question if you know what you're talking about and can provide a how-to.  That's why the option is right there near the "Post" button.  Alternatively, I find that often I post a question then days later discover the answer so I come back and post it.  Just remember that we're building a searchable database here.  Be Nice, and Be Accurate.  That goes for any answer, whether the OP is yourself or not.